# Python re.findall a specific word from a string

Tags: python

I want to find all the words  **'quick'** from the following string.

```
myString = ''' hi quick is qui
ck is some thing is very big and quick is
it has got some backend quic
k 
'''
```

my code.

```
In [39]: re.findall('quick',myString , re.M)
Out[39]: ['quick', 'quick']
```

Comment: You found them! Good job! What's your question?

Comment: but some 'quick' are missing. some are spanning over multiple lines. I wan t to find them all.

Comment: Then put that in your question. `qui/nck` is not `quick`.

Answer (score 2):

The string includes newline characters and whitespace at the end of those lines. Remove them, and then process the string using your command:

```
s = ''.join([line.rstrip() for line in myString.splitlines()])
re.findall('quick', s, re.M)
```